# How to insert data of wpf datagrid to two different sql tables?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid

```
for (int i = 0; i < purrecord.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into purchases (id, name, pack, piece, Rate, total, discountper, discountrs, bonus, totaldisc, time, company) values('" + postid1.Text + "',@name, @pack, @piece, @Rate, @total, @discountper, @discountrs, @bonus, @totaldisc, '" + crnttime + "', '" + company.SelectedItem + "') ", con); //...-->Add other parametres
                           

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", (purrecord.Columns[0].GetCellContent(purrecord.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pack", (purrecord.Columns[1].GetCellContent(purrecord.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@piece", (purrecord.Columns[2].GetCellContent(purrecord.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", (purrecord.Columns[3].GetCellContent(purrecord.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", (purrecord.Columns[4].GetCellContent(purrecord.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discountper", (purrecord.Columns[5].GetCellContent(purrecord.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discountrs", (purrecord.Columns[6].GetCellContent(purrecord.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bonus", (purrecord.Columns[7].GetCellContent(purrecord.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totaldisc", (purrecord.Columns[8].GetCellContent(purrecord.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I want to the content value of pack and total to another table named productlist where brandname=@name. I am tring to use the following query but i doesn't work.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into productlist (stock, net) values (@pack, @total) where ([brandname] = @name1)", con); //...-->Add other parametres
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name1", (purrecord.Columns[0].GetCellContent(purrecord.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pack", (purrecord.Columns[1].GetCellContent(purrecord.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", (purrecord.Columns[4].GetCellContent(purrecord.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It says incorrect syntax near where.

Comment: You can not use WHERE in INSERT Sql Command

Comment: What is the structure of your tables in database?

Comment: i just realized that we don't use where command with insert command instead we use update. Thanks for the help!

Comment: But UPDATE only used to modify already added data, you have to use INSERT to add new data

Comment: The query is used to keep a record of all the purchases that have been made.  while 2nd query is used to insert all purchases stock to the products tables so the user can see how much stock is available.